# asp.net form authenciation cookie does not work in ie8

Tags: asp.net, form-authentication

In our asp.net application,we use the form authenciation.

And we use the iframe for layout ,but all the link of the src is inside our domain.

Sometimes if user login using ie8,he will always redirect to the login page,then I use the developer tool,I found that no cookie is set in the browser.

However,in some other machine user can login with ie8.

It works well in firefox and ie7.

And the name of our server is `sbl21`,no un-allowed characters.

This is the form config:

```
<forms name="LoginCookieName" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout="40" />
```

If we add the `cookieless="UseUri"`, then user can login,but if he click any links in the page,a alert box will dispaly which show user is not logined.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am the author,and this problem is solved.

Why the user can not login is caused that the cookie is expired once it is write to ie.

And this is because the time in the server computer is old than that of the client.

(We change the server computer time for some consideration).

Answer (score 0):

Chances are some of your pages using subdomain, like `http://www.sbl21` and others using `http://sbl121`. Browser under such circumstances consider the domain to be different.